# Strange noises/Entity 303 or Herobrine noise?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ok, I am just playing my default creative world, adding stuff onto an end city, and then suddenly the default Minecraft music glitches and ominous music comes on. I quit the world. Is this Entity 303? Or just a glitch?

Comment: Were you in the End dimension when this happened? (Since you mentioned the End city)

Comment: Yeah, I was in the End.

Comment: I spawned in an end city for some reason, too.

Comment: When I used the end portal.

Answer (score 4):

Neither, it is just the deafult song in the end. [This](https://youtu.be/nviIB8A7LgM?t=70) is probably what you heard.